# Designating dynamic start in time-series vectors in R

Tags: r, dynamic, time-series

I have some problems with time-series designation of vectors in R.

I work with time-series and when I want to set a vector to a certain period, I feel quite confident about how to do it. I have simply done as follow `name<- ts(name, frequency=12, start=c(2007,1))`. As you can see I have monthly data

I am making an R template for colleagues to use, and I want them to be able to carry out a recursive ARIMA regression from any given starting point. That is, I have a range of in-sample predicted valued and I want to designate a start-value that is n monthly observation after 2007 (or whatever start data is used), where n is the start-value of the recursive regression.

Comment: What is exactly your question? What did you try yourself? Basically, [How to make a great R reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

`first` and `last` from the `xts` time-series package do exactly what you want.i.e. to get the first 2 months of an object x:

```
first(x, '2 months’)
```

or the last 6 weeks:

```
last(x, '6 weeks’)
```

Valid period.types are: secs, seconds, mins, minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, quarters, and years. As always you can find much more detailed information using `?xts::first`.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your response. My vector is a vector of predictions. Because of have partitioned my time series vector into a training set and a test set, the prediction vector goes from 85:113 (the 29 values of my test set). Note, however, I want to be able to change the length of the test set.

I want to plot these predictions alongside the observed values, which are a time-series, thus the former should be turned into a time series. So I tried to use `name<- ts(name, frequency=12, start=c(2007,1))` , but don't know how to add the length of my training set in months to the start date.

Comment: Please let me know, if there is any part that is unclear.

Comment: I am afraid I can not be of much help regarding your comment as I use the `xts` and `zoo` packages for my research with time series and have `timeseries` not installed. Have you tried `as.ts` to convert to ts-object ?